# How to implement an audio player for Android using MediaPlayer And MediaController?

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player

I want to create an Android application that is a client for an Internet radio station. And I want it look native to Android? But im confused with Android API logic and documentation. What i've got is that I need MediaPlayer and MediaController classes. Am I right, and is there any good example of AUDIO player for Android?

Especially, I'm very interested how to use `MediaPlayer` and `MediaController` classes together.

UPD:

Finally I've got the code, that does exactly what I want:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
Uri u = Uri.parse(%file_uri%));    
i.setData(u);    
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can look at those links :

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

Hope it will help.

[EDIT]

You have also some example on the official android developer website :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: I've created a sample app that has a pretty clean solution and will help you get started (https://github.com/saulpower/MyMediaPlayer).