# android, RESULT_OK forcing for Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There is an application. It allows users to watch a lot of videofiles from one web media resource. I know that it is possible to force a result for an activity like in the following example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

But it is in case of Activity class inheritance. Is there any possibility to force RESULT_OK (for example) in the following case:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mp4url), "video/mp4");
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_PLAYBACK_FINISHED);
```

where mp4url is a String variable, VIDEO_PLAYBACK_FINISHED is an int variable (a keyword for request).

As you can see there is no Activity class to work with. Everithing depends on a Video player users working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry that is not possible, since you are using the device's default media player.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963996/android-embed-default-audio-player-in-app-activity) explains that embedding of media players in your app is also not possible.