# How to close Android player

Tags: android, android-intent

```
File file = new File(mFileName);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

In my application, I am using this code and playing an audio file but when it's finished playing the player doesn't close. Is there a way to close the player after the whole audio is played ?

Comment: I am not sure,but maybe using a startActivityforResult should do some help.

Comment: Why not play the audio file with MediaPlayer class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: if you mean I just need to finish there. No result

Comment: bcoz I need it to play with default player... I don't know how to open default player using mediaPlayer

Comment: may this helps you with MediaPlayer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220575/how-to-implement-an-audio-player-for-android-using-mediaplayer-and-mediacontroll

Answer (score 1):

For example https://gist.github.com/850599.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my android phone, after the music was played the `default player` closed and return to the last activity. So Maybe it depends on the configuration of `default player`.

I think it's a better way to use MediaPlayer instand of `default player` which is more certain.

By the way, You can try kill the `default player` process. Get the time of the music, and start a thread to kill the process after the play time.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill" +pid);
```