# Playing audio repeat Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am playing some audio via a button is pressed.  The audio plays fine, but i want to be able to spam the button and let the audio play play play play.  Even stop where its playing and play again if i press the button.   Now when i press the button, the audio just plays all the way through and nothing happens if i press the button while the audio is playing.  Here is my code:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);

        Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is your requirement now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement an audio player for Android using MediaPlayer And MediaController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220575/how-to-implement-an-audio-player-for-android-using-mediaplayer-and-mediacontroll)

Answer (score 0):

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
mp.setLooping(true);

        Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Replace this code with your existing code. if you want to repeat your audio  then you have to set the looping property to true.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I hope I got this right:

You want to play the audio clip for every time you press the button and the clip should be played completely, before the next clip starts.

Here's what I'd do:

Create a new integer attribute.
`private int i = 0;`

Increment it every time you press the button.

```
Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IUP();
    }
});

public synchronized void IUP(){
    i++;
}

public synchronized void IDOWN(){
    i--;
}

public synchronized int getI(){ return i; }

public void startAudio(){ mp.start(); }

public boolean isPlaying(){ return mp.isPlaying(); }
```

Use a seperate thread for the player.

```
Thread player_thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run(){
       while(true){
           if(getI() > 0 && !isPlaying()){
               IDOWN();
               startAudio();
           }
       }
    }
}).start();
```

Or use an [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) on the MediaPlayer.

Tell me if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);

Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(play_button.getText().toString().equals("Stop")
        {
            mp.stop();
            play_button.setText("Play");
        }
        else
        {
            mp.start();
            play_button.setText("Stop");
        }
    }
});
```